# Open url given by stdout from node --inspect command

Tags: node.js, bash, macos

Alright here's a fun one, we get the following stdout:

```
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@60cd6e859b9f557d2312f5bf532f6aec5f284980/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/a7a2a58d-dfd1-4cc6-875c-47da78adeb1b
```

when we run a command like so:

```
node --inspect --debug-brk bin/www.js
```

I was thinking of creating a bash script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NODE_DEBUG_OUTPUT=$(node --inspect --debug-brk bin/www.js)
open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"/ getUrl(${NODE_DEBUG_OUTPUT})
```

but here's where my bash skills end - how can I implement the `getUrl` function so that I can get the url from the output?

I am pretty certain that if we pass a url to the open function in bash, it will open a browser, in this case though it has to be Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bash command to extract the url

```
url=$(grep 'chrome-devtools://' <(node --inspect bin/www.js $@ 2>&1))
```

**Explanation**

- The `2>&1` tells the shell to redirect stderr to stdout.
- The `node` command is run within <( `node` ), this is called [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and behaves like a read-only file with the contents being the stdout of the command (`node` in this case)

**Other Issues**

- There is a bug, filed recently [Chrome DevTools not able to connect to Node inspect since 7.5.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11591)
- Version 7.4.0 is reported to work
- To open a chrome-devtools url from the command line requires some AppleScript, fortunately someone's already done that:

> [chrome-node-devtools-refresh.sh](https://gist.github.com/jscheel/152431a9b8d2753800fae6d2f536d50b)

So the command would be something like this:

```
chrome-node-devtools-refresh.sh $(grep 'chrome-devtools://' \
    <(node --inspect bin/www.js $@ 2>&1))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative

So I am probably not answering your question but I want to give this as a simpler solution to the higher problem you are trying to resolve.

There is a `npm` package called `node-inspector`. This package provides the same functionality as you need from chrome dev-tools. Here is the description from their github page :

> Node Inspector is a debugger interface for Node.js applications that
>   uses the Blink Developer Tools (formerly WebKit Web Inspector).

### How do you Install?

`npm install -g node-inspector`

### How do you use?

```
node-debug app.js
```

where `app.js` is your js file. you can do `node-debug bin/www` in your case

### What does it do?

Here is a gif for you to show what it does

[image]

### Summary

The `node-inspector` package can help you achieve the functionality you desire. i.e. launch chrome to debug your js code. I feel this is a easier option. Also you can read more about this to explore additional use cases if you have

From the developers of this package:

> The node-debug command will load Node Inspector in your default
>   browser.
>
> NOTE: Node Inspector works in Chrome and Opera only. You have to
>   re-open the inspector page in one of those browsers if another browser
>   is your default web browser (e.g. Safari or Internet Explorer). Node
>   Inspector works almost exactly as the Chrome Developer Tools. Read the
>   excellent DevTools overview to get started.

Comment: ah yes, I forgot, does this actually launch the chrome browser, or open a new tab? I actually would like to solve the original problem, but you did get an upvote from me.

Comment: ughh, it doesn't always open a new browser window, so unfortunately this solution is not going to work most likely, even though it was a good idea. Also, I would be somewhat afraid that node-inspector will not be well maintained since the code seemed to move into Node core.

Comment: manishg you should check out the answer from @667, that Chrome extension works really well.

Comment: That's strange !

Answer (score -1):

This is really close! The only thing that's not working is that chrome is not actually opening a url, it just opens to google.com

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/

(node --inspect --debug-brk bin/www.js $@ &> debug-server.log) &

sleep 1;  // wait for the stdout to get written to file...

LINE=$(grep -n "chrome-devtools" debug-server.log | awk '{print $2}')

echo " => Supposed chrome-devtools link => '$LINE'";

Google\ Chrome "${LINE}"
```

anybody know why the "Google\ Chrome" command would not open the url provided as the first argument?

Comment: Maybe try using `open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args ...`

Comment: do you mean: open -a ?

Comment: I tried, I can't get open -a to work...the reason is that the open command think it's a file, not a url

Comment: Is chrome your default browser, and what if you leave out the Google Chrome.app portion and try just using `open -a "${line}"`? Also, you might try leaving out the `-a` option as well...

Comment: It's possible you'll want to use `devtools-terminal` or pass the arguments with `--devtools-flags` perhaps. There' s a ton of command-line options available, so maybe have a look here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#auto-open-devtools-for-tabs

Comment: the open command thinks it's a file, with or without the -a flag